# hibernate custom types for jodatime (version conflict?)

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, jodatime, wildfly

I have an entity with following property:

```
@Type(type = "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
protected DateTime time;
```

and I get following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
        at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeSet(CustomType.java:158)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2843)
```

I'm using jboss wildfly, which is using hibernate 4.3.1.
I have joda-time-2.3.jar and joda-time-hibernate-1.3.jar in my ear.
Are those versions not working together correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the website [joda-time-hibernate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/) it is stated that this project relates to Hibernate version 3.6, see:

"Please note that version 1.3 is for Hibernate 3.6 and not Hibernate 4.0 (as the Hibernate team have made another incompatible change). The [usertype project](http://usertype.sourceforge.net/) handles Hibernate 4.0. It is also more up to date and more complete than this project in general."